# PostgreSQL Date Check Costraint

Tags: postgresql, date

How could I add a Check-costraint for Date type in PostgreSQL?

For example,

```
 CHECK 'DateXYZ>01/02/98'
```

A typecast is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table foo
(
    some_date date not null check (some_date > date '1998-02-01');
);
```

More details in the manual:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS